# Make the subview at centre or some height from the top

Tags: ios, swift, gmsmapview

`@IBOutlet weak var viewmap: GMSMapView!`

I have one mapview in my vc called `viewmap` . And one uiview called `mapInfoWindow`. Now when ever user click on any pin my map, that particular pin details will be show in that `mapInfoWindow`. Now the position is bit at top where my `mapInfoWindow` is getting hide my my search bar.

I need to make the position bit bottom from my top.Here is the code :

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView!, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker!) -> UIView!
    {
        print("markerInfoWindow called!!!")
        let firstview = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 275, height: 195))
        self.mapInfoWindow = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomInfoWindow", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! CustomInfoWindow

        self.mapInfoWindow.ClickForMore.text = "click_here_for_more".localized
        marker.tracksInfoWindowChanges = true

// data for fetching details
     self.mapInfoWindow.bgview.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.mapInfoWindow.bgview.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
        self.mapInfoWindow.bgview.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        self.mapInfoWindow.bgview.layer.shadowRadius = 2
        self.mapInfoWindow.bgview.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear


        firstview.addSubview(self.mapInfoWindow)

        return firstview
    }
```

How can i achive that. I tried giving `y` value but not working.Any idea ?

Also tried :

`mapInfoWindow.center.y = firstview.center.y - 80` -  not wokring

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a view's individual frame properties, and centre should be spelled center. Here's an [extension](https://gist.github.com/nbasham/84ce5b1fdec949115999b738217bde65) that allows you to position a view's individual values.

Using the extension the example above can then be written:

`mapInfoWindow.centerY = firstview.centerY - 80`

Comment: `mapInfoWindow.centerY = firstview.centerY - 80` this is hiding my uiview half

Comment: @david I don't know what you mean by ' this is hiding my uiview half'

Comment: my `mapInfoWindow` height is reduced from top.

Comment: @david The extension will also let you set the `mapInfoWindow` height e.g. `mapInfoWindow.height = 100`. I'm not clear on what the issue is, perhaps a screenshot would help.